# wxPython Swap Images

Tags: image, wxpython

I have been trying to swap 2 pictures in a list. I am adding the list to a GridSizer of 1 row and 2 cols. I have one horizontal BoxSizer where I am adding the GridSizer along with a button upon which, when clicked, the pictures are supposed to be swapped. But I am getting type error string or unicode required.
I am using Python 2.7.6 and wxPython 2.8.12.1 (gtk2-unicode) on a Linux Mint 64-bit laptop. Below is the part of my program where the error is occurring.
Please help.

Thanks.

```
def OnOk(self, event):
    x = wx.Image(self.ic[0], wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).Scale(200, 200)
    y = wx.Image(self.ic[1], wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).Scale(200, 200)
    self.ic[0].SetBitmap(wx.StaticBitmap(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.BitmapFromImage(y)))
    self.ic[1].SetBitmap(wx.StaticBitmap(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.BitmapFromImage(x)))
    self.Refresh()
```

Comment: Can you provide a small runnable example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quite do not understand what `self.ic` is supposed to be (a list of `wx.StaticBitmap` instances or a list of `wx.Bitmap` instances). You seem to mix up the both. A `StaticBitmap` is a `wxPython` widget, a `wx.Bitmap` is, well, just a data structure holding bitmap data.

See a working example below:

```
import wx

class bmpframe(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)

        pnl = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        # lazy way to make two discernable bitmaps
        # Warning: alpha does not work on every platform/version
        bmp1 = wx.EmptyBitmapRGBA(64, 64, alpha=0)
        bmp2 = wx.EmptyBitmapRGBA(64, 64, alpha=1)

        static_bitmap_1 = wx.StaticBitmap(pnl, -1, bitmap=bmp1)
        static_bitmap_2 = wx.StaticBitmap(pnl, -1, bitmap=bmp2)
        self.stbmp1 = static_bitmap_1
        self.stbmp2 = static_bitmap_2

        self.btn_swap = wx.Button(pnl, -1, u'Swap…')

        szmain = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        szmain.Add(static_bitmap_1, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 4)
        szmain.Add(static_bitmap_2, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 4)
        szmain.Add(self.btn_swap, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 4)

        pnl.SetSizer(szmain)
        szmain.Fit(self)

        self.btn_swap.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_swap)

    def on_swap(self, evt):
        print 'EVT_BUTTON'
        bmp1 = self.stbmp1.GetBitmap()
        bmp2 = self.stbmp2.GetBitmap()
        self.stbmp1.SetBitmap(bmp2)
        self.stbmp2.SetBitmap(bmp1)
        self.Refresh()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(redirect=False)
    frm = bmpframe(None, -1, 'testbmpswap')
    frm.Show()

    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Yes, ic is a list of StaticBitmap.
`self.ic.append(wx.StaticBitmap(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.BitmapFromImage(img1), name="Pic1"))`

Thank you very much. Your code solved the problem.